# How to remove * from importhtml output data in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to remove * in following data output ....

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/BAJFINANCE?expiry=26MAY2022","Table",1)
```

I want to know the formula to do it.

Comment: Add the link of the shared google spreadsheet sample.

Comment: Just want to make BAJFINANCE &8000 to make variable I.e. I want to take these values from a cell in which I can give values whatever I required........https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/BAJFINANCE/strike/8000?expiry=28APR2022

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(iferror(substitute(IMPORTHTML(A1,"Table",1),"*","")*1,substitute(IMPORTHTML(A1,"Table",1),"*","")))
```

if you want to transform values from text to umeric

```
=arrayformula(iferror(
substitute(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&A1&"/strike/"&B1&"?expiry="&C1,"Table",1),"*","")*1,
substitute(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&A1&"/strike/"&B1&"?expiry="&C1,"Table",1),"*","")))
```

[image]

Comment: Just want to make BAJFINANCE &8000 to make variable I.e. I want to take these values from a cell in which I can give values whatever I required........https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/BAJFINANCE/strike/8000?expiry=28APR2022

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk
Plz see the sheet what I want to ask ???

Comment: Plz see the link wherein I have explained the data I want to fetch.......https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Authorization given and plz make it also variable as in previous so that I can use for all stocks

Comment: Plz I don't want %value so how to remove it

Comment: 2260 is retrieve by `=index(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/ACC","//li[@class='collection-item']//li/p"),1,1)`

Comment: 10;10 is retrieve by `=regexextract(index(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/ACC","//li[@class='collection-item']//li/p"),1,3),"[0-9.]+")*1`

Comment: In 2260 retrieving formula I want to take value from a cell let's say from "A2" to finnd this value for many stocks. Could you suggest formula plz.

Comment: `=index(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&A2,"//li[@class='collection-item']//li/p"),1,1)`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk                                      Plz help to get the data....

Comment: in Sheet5? this way `=index(importxml(A1,"//li[@class='collection-item']//li/p"),1,1)`

Comment: Sir it's very slow to retrieve data. And for many stocks(206) too much slow and for few no result.Is there any way for faster data retrieval ???

Comment: Sir how to open new topic to get advice by you. I want yor advice specially plz

Comment: Sir I raised a new topic but don't know how to share you link ???0


I tried to import historical data by using =IMPORTHTML("https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=RELIANCE","Table",1) but got no result. How to import data table from above link plz ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72070582/18865210

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is closed! however, I took a look, and it seems there is no possibility due to the fact that the site is well protected against web scrapping

Comment: I don't Python, you can try by Selenium. I am not an expert! Or may be with excel.

Comment: =regexextract(index(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/ACC","//li[@class='collection-item']//li/p"),1,3),"[0-9.]+")*1           sir in this formula given by you to me how to get +/- sign before the value Plz

Comment: this way `=regexextract(index(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/ACC","//li[@class='collection-item']//li/p"),1,3),"[\-\+0-9.]+")*1`

Comment: https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/MARUTI?expiry=30JUN2022
Sir I want pcr and intraday pcr values for 30june2022 expiry whose values are 0.77 & 0.76 respectively. Plz help me by formula

Comment: `=importxml(url,"//span[@class='white-text red darken-1']")` next time, open a new topic please

Comment: =importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/MARUTI?expiry=30JUN2022","//span[@class='white-text, red darken-1']"
Sir it's giving formula parse error

Comment: not at all, it works! give me a spreadsheet and I will demonstrate it. Here is a screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSDXR.png

Comment: Got it bracket was not closed

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk
Plz show me here sir. It's still not retrieved

Comment: why do you put a comma here `white-text,red darken-1`? .... please copy without error the class name!

Comment: Sir one minor issue in above query ...data for different stocks are in 3 colour set red/blue/green depending on their values. How to get those plz. I have given some screen shots in above google sheet plz

Comment: don't continue to ask here questions, you will be excluded from stackoverflow and me too! post a new topic and I will answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72396006/18865210

Answer (score -1):

or try just:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&A2&"/strike/"&B2&"?expiry="&C2, 
 "table", 1), "*", ))
```

to not import stuff twice and save resources. yes the output is text but if you intend further calculations with those numbers, they will be auto-converted to numeric values

[image]

Comment: https://niftyinvest.com/max-pain/AARTIIND?expiry=30JUN2022
I tried to retrieve data over black background as max pain for AARTIIND is 740. Just want digit value only... "740". How to get that plz