# Data in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, indexing, import

I tried following formula for getting pcr data...

```
=importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/MARUTI?expiry=30JUN2022","//span[@class='white-text red darken-1']"
```

For different stocks the values are in 3 different colours red/blue/green depending on their values predefined.
How to get the common formula so that it can retrieve data in whatever colour plz ????

Other Data Links...

1- https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/indigo?expiry=30jun2022

2- https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/britannia?expiry=30jun2022

3- https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/MARUTI?expiry=30JUN2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this generic xpath `//h5//span[@class[contains(.,'white-text ')]]`

```
=transpose(importxml(A2,"//h5//span[@class[contains(.,'white-text ')]]"))
```

[image]

edit: you can use queries to reorder columns and select by specific criteria.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/indigo?expiry=30jun2022","table",1),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col4>0.6 and Col7>0.7 and Col1 <> 'IOC' and Col1 <> 'POWERGRID ' ")
```

Comment: Nifty invest is useless for me sir. Plz remove it

Comment: Done, this way you have a flexible solution with only one formula and you can retrive values even if you encounter new colors.

Comment: Sir plz can you convert it in arrayformula . I tried like this but failed....=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A67,"","",transpose(query(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/"&A3&"?expiry=30jun2022","//span[@class[contains(.,'white-text ')]]"),"select Col1 offset 1",0))))

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0XzeSrif_I1Q/?hl=sv - 

ARRAYFORMULA does not support IMPORTXML, IMPORTHTML.

Comment: By the way, I have simplified the formula

Comment: Sir data retrieval is very slow due to multiple queries. Only few loding. Is there any mean to load faster plz ???

Comment: i am afraid that there is no other possibilities unless dividing the data into multiple sheets. How many importxml do you have?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EojSW8nJNGyGcZAIKJAYLyTyB7Aj8e53LOn1gi5v4Nw/edit?usp=drivesdk         sir this is my final sheet with all your formulae told till now. No further data import needed except collectin data at one place on dashboard sheet. Next exp data is twice and I will remove one of them whichever will have faster loading.

Comment: 1-remove function where you do nt have any symbol in data | 2-remove columns E and F in data that will divide the calls by 2 | 3-columns F and G in calls : do not importxml twice, try to find a unique formula to do so | 4-don't call again importxml for old dates, just keep the values instead of the formula ...

Comment: Sir,  point not clear... No 4- don't call again importxml for old dates....

Comment: sorry, error, these values are for different symbols (I made a mistake by believing that they were for different dates)

Comment: Sir how to rearrange order of columns in importhtml data table....
=IMPORTHTML("niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/NIFTY","Table",1)

Comment: use `=query(importrange(___),"select ColX,ColY,ColZ")` and put the values X,Y,Z as you wish

Comment: Sir I want to remove some rows let's say having IOC , POWERGRID etc . Is it possible plz ?=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/… Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col4>0.6 and Col7>0.7")

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Sir need data on black strip as max pain 740. Only want the digit "740" . Plz help one more time ... https://niftyinvest.com/max-pain/AARTIIND?expiry=30JUN2022

Comment: Sir Plz this is last one 

Comment: open a new topic please, I am not allowed to continue here!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72589478/18865210

Answer (score 1):

for `Pcr`:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A2, 
 "//span[@class='white-text red darken-1'] | 
  //span[@class='white-text light-blue lighten-1'] |
  //span[@class='white-text green darken-1']"), 1)
```

[image]

---

for `Intraday Pcr`:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A2, 
 "//span[@class='white-text red darken-1'] | 
  //span[@class='white-text light-blue lighten-1'] |
  //span[@class='white-text green darken-1']"), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk
Sir plz see the sheet where I have shown what I want.... Plz search the required stocks and see the colours of data... Plz help me to get the common formula so that it can be dragged down for all

Comment: @Brijesh did you try solutions from the above answer?

Comment: I got my data. Thanks a lot 

Comment: Sir how to rearrange order of columns in importhtml data
=IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/NIFTY","Table",1)

Comment: @Brijesh with query: `=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/NIFTY","Table",1, "select Col2,Col1,Col3", )`

Comment: Sir I want to remove some rows let's say having IOC , POWERGRID etc . Is it possible plz ?=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/NIFTY","Table",1),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col4>0.6 and Col7>0.7")