# Conditional removal of rows in importhtml data output

Tags: arrays, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, substitution, google-query-language

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
substitute(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&D2&"?expiry="&$B$2,"Table",1),"*","")*1,
substitute(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&D2&"?expiry="&$B$2,"Table",1),"*","")))
```

where D2 = `MARUTI` and B2 = `30Jun2022` let's say...

Now I want to remove the row in which all columns value is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    =query(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(substitute(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&D2&"?expiry="&$B$2,"Table",1),"*",""), substitute(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&D2&"?expiry="&$B$2,"Table",1),"",""))),
"where "&ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" and ",, "Col"&SEQUENCE(11,1,1,1)&" is not null")),1)
```

Comment: Sir Plz have a look here..... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Sir it was not what I asked. Plz try to get my query. I want to remove only that row whose all column values are "0" not  "-". Actually this row is due to advertising s on the website, I think which disturb my calculations.

Comment: Max Pain for AARTIIND is 740. Sir Plz I want this digit value "740". Link..... niftyinvest.com/max-pain/AARTIIND?expiry=30JUN2022. Sir Plz give me generalized formula so that it can take input from any cell value

Comment: Sir my another query above Plz ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245531/discussion-between-brijesh-and-mike-steelson).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72645453/18865210

Comment: This seems quite impossible to do because the page is built in javascript, and requires making a request with the post method (this means that the parameters cannot be concatenated to the url). I will follow the post while waiting for further advice.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk      ....sir plz my this query pending from a very long time. Sir plz give me general formula so that I can use it for different stocks and different expires.... as in earlier suggestions plz last one

Comment: No sir it's different query . Here link of website is different than earlier answers. I have placed D2 & B2 values in above sheet I shared you. This is importxml query .Plz have a look again 

Comment: Sir Plz open this link...                                                                                             https://niftyinvest.com/max-pain/AARTIIND?expiry=30JUN2022      then there is a black strip with white text over it as MAX PAIN FOR AARTIIND IS 720. I want this 720 digit. In your edit formula link is something else which is for other data.

Comment: `=importxml(url,"//h6[@class='center-align padding-10 black darken-2 white-text']")`

Comment: Sir giving formula parse error. I have done in shared sheet to you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I still can't write in your spreadsheet ... here is the solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlzuy.png

Comment: Sir settings allowed. Sorry angry on myself. Everytime I'm getting formula parse error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72750771/18865210

Comment: I have also shared Google sheet link there

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&D2&"?expiry="&$B$2,"table",1),"*",)*1,
 SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&D2&"?expiry="&$B$2,"table",1),"*",))),
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "Col"&SEQUENCE(11)&" <>0"))
```

[image]