# Data import for drop down menu scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I gone through the formula...
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/option-chain#","Table",1) but failed to get any output saying formula parse error.When I'm going to copy the link there is no name of script for which I want the link but # symbol is there at the place of name of script.As there is 2 drop down menu let's say one for crude oil and second for July month expiry date. How to get the data/link for desired script??
[image: webpage and drop-down image is included here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you're trying to import is dynamically loaded with the drop-down menus. This data is loaded by JavaScript, therefore is not retrievable by IMPORT functions in Google Sheets. If you disable JavaScript and reload this site, you will notice that you're not able to retrieve the table. You can double check this by clicking the lock icon next to the URL bar > 'Site settings' > set JavaScript to 'Block'. You can refer to this [thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/111939291?&msgid=112017200) for more details.