# Substitute formula retrieving less data table

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to follow two ways ...

1. To remove * only ... `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&M5&"?expiry="&$N$5,"table",1),"*",)*1,SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&M5&"?expiry="&$N$5,"table",1),"*",))),"Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5, Col3, Col6, Col9, Col7, Col8, Col10, Col11 where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "Col" &SEQUENCE(11) &" <> 0"))`
2. To remove * and replacing "-" by zero simultaneously... `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&M5&"?expiry="&$N$5,"table",1),"*",""),"-","0")*1,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&M5&"?expiry="&$N$5,"table",1),"*",""),"-","0"))),"Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5, Col3, Col6, Col9, Col7, Col8, Col10, Col11 where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "Col" &SEQUENCE(11) &" <> 0"))`

But result is less data in 2nd case. How to get all data in 2nd case. Consider Col6 data to compare plz. Cell values let's say .....
M5=BAJFINANCE   N5=30June2022

Comment: Please help people in the community properly replicate your setup by providing a **Sample sheet**, **data** & the **expected result** you'd like to get. Looking at your sample function, it is quite hard to fully grasp what you' re trying to do. We do not know what the values of `M5` & `$N$5` cells are. Kindly check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycM9PeE36QR45z_HHjYG0fbtC_R3RSMw5kgjEtj3IKI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Plz see above sheet in which I have explained my query with data output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&A1&"?expiry="&B1, "table", 1)&"", "*", ), "^-$", "0"), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/"&A1&"?expiry="&B1, "table", 1)&"", "*", ), "^-$", "0"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11")*1),,9^9))}, 
 "select Col1, Col2,Col4,Col5,Col3,Col6,Col9,Col7,Col8,Col10,Col11 
  where Col12 <> '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'", 1)&"♥"),,9^9)), "♥", 1, 0))
```

[image]